# Keyboard Events in As3

Tags: actionscript-3, keyboard

Okay, so i'm a total noob. I want to advance a scene in as3 with any keyboard button. Here's my code, can you help me?

```
import flash.events.Event;
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startGame);
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, asteroidMovement);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, startGameWithKeys);

stop();


function startGameWithKeys(e:KeyboardEvent){
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, asteroidMovement);
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startGame);
    gotoAndStop(1, "Scene 2");
}

function startGame(e:MouseEvent)
{
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, asteroidMovement);
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startGame);
    gotoAndStop(1, "Scene 2");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your listener code is fine, it should be dispatching whenever you press any key. Your scene might be named incorrectly.

Anyway, always try avoiding the use of scenes in flash. Use frames if it make you feel more comfortable working in flash IDE, but always avoid scenes. The next step should be using a development IDE like FlashBuilder and avoiding timeline code :)

Answer (score 0):

No need to create two functions for similar actions, use following code,

Also jumping to scene statement is perfect.

```
 function startGame(e:Event):void
 {
     //Put your code here
     trace(e.type);

     gotoAndStop(1, "Scene 2");
 }

 stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startGame, false, 0, true);
 stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, startGame, false, 0, true);
```